# how can i add an http:// url to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have been trying to add an HTTP: URL to Facebook it's not working 
or is there a way that I can make my app public and free for any type of URLs?

```
 to transfer information.
Until octopus-bn updates its security settings, 
you won't be able to use Facebook to log into it.``

i am getting the following error
```

Comment: Add a HTTP url where?

Comment: Into Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
Facebook app setting Since the host I am using is not an https:// So I don't how to fix the issue

Comment: I even think that if they was a way that I can turn off Enforce HTTPS setting it would work

Comment: It has to be https.